# WCF Service - Know when users connected?

Tags: c#, wcf, iis

I have two WCF services IIS hosted, the customer would like me to create a dashboard application that tells them when someone is connected, so they dont reboot the server while there are active sessions.

I was wondering if there was a better approach to monitor the WCF services, other than say a small database or flat file that tracks active sessions?

Does IIS/WCF have a method to look for active sessions?

Brian

Answer (score 1):

You can use AppFabric! It already have a dashboard.

Take a look:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee677236(v=azure.10).aspx

Comment: Wish it was that easy, seems it does not work on the server, no events have ever been logged. Plus Im not sure its instant, from what I can tell there is a delay as the SQL agent has to run for that dashboard to populate. I think i am just going to end up writing a text file to the drive when a user is active and then just place a program to check for that file existance.

Comment: Well, you can use perfmon with these counters: http://blog.monitis.com/index.php/2012/04/02/important-iis7-counters/